# Does chainercv project the full copy of original faster R-CNN caffe code?

Tags: chainer

I find the chainercv project : https://github.com/chainer/chainercv
I have read this code, the comment and code is excellent, but few detail still confuse me. I wonder:
Does this code the exactly same logic as https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn
Which is orignal caffe implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote that code.
The logic is not completely the same as py-faster-rcnn, but the difference is very subtle.
Also, you can see more details here.

https://github.com/chainer/chainercv/tree/master/examples/faster_rcnn#difference-in-the-runtime-behaviour-from-the-original-code

The changes are necessary for consistency in the library.
As a side note, I made that change after completely replicating the behavior of py-faster-rcnn using Chainer.
I checked correctness by checking outputs of my own code and py-faster-rcnn to be within the margin of numerical errors.

Comment: I am care about the tail part of the network, is this tail part of it (after RoI pooling score&loss and so on) the same as original code?

Comment: Offset used in a function `loc2bbox` is different.